# for loop don't increment set i=0

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

i have a problem with my little cmd script.

```
set i=1
set tmp=0

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
set /A i+=1
echo %i%=%%A
)
echo %i%
```

My question is why the line in loop `echo %i%=%%A` give this output

```
1=text one
1=text two
1=text three
4
```

Instead this

```
2=text one
3=text two
4=text three
4
```

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it work now

```
set i=1
set tmp=0

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
set /A i+=1
echo !i!=%%A
)
echo %i%
```